# mail merge - removing lines with zero values

Tags: ms-word

I am trying to create a mail merge, but I don't want to display lines with zero values. Currently, my merge displays the following information:

```
BASIC 164,233.33
HAZARD 5,000.00
SHIFT/CALL 84,480.00
SPECIALIST 0.00
TEACHING 14,301.92
RAA 0.00 
RURAL 0.00
DOMESTIC 0.00
OTHER EARNINGS 0.00
```

This is the structure of my mail merge:

```
BASIC «BASIC_SALARY»
HAZARD «HAZARD_ALLOWANCE»
SHIFT/CALL «CALL_DUTY_ALLOWANCE»
SPECIALIST «SPECIALIST_ALLOWANCE»
TEACHING «ACADEMIC_ALLOWANCE»
RAA «RAA» 
RURAL «RURAL_POSTING»
DOMESTIC «DOMESTIC_ALLOWANCE»
OTHER EARNINGS «OTHER_ALOWANCES»
```

Is there a way to modify my code so that the lines with zero values do not appear in the mail merge?

Answer (score 0):

First, select the field codes and use Toggle field codes so that insteead of, e.g.

```
BASIC «BASIC_SALARY»
```

you see the field coding, i.e.

```
BASIC { MERGEFIELD BASIC_SALARY }
```

In this case, you have to change the field coding for each line that should be suppressed from

```
TAG: { MERGEFIELD FIELDNAME }
```

to

```
{ IF { MERGEFIELD FIELDNAME } = 0 "" "TAG: { MERGEFIELD FIELDNAME }
" }
```

where all the `{}` are the special field code brace pairs that you can insert on Windows desktop Word using ctrl-F9, and where you put insert a paragraph before the final double-quotation mark so that the final `" }` is in a different paragraph from the preceding field coding. Also, ensure the (If you click the Show/Hide Formatting Marks button in Word (the one in the `Home` tab that looks like this: ¶), the fields should look like this:

```
{ IF { MERGEFIELD FIELDNAME } = 0 "" "TAG: { MERGEFIELD FIELDNAME }¶
" }
```

The `IF` field is picky about the spacing around the comparison sign (`=` in this example). IMO it is simpler to ensure that there is one space either side of the sign.

Because this field coding inserts the paragraph mark when the value of FIELDNAME is zero, you do not want another paragraph mark at the end of the field. So if you have two fields FIELD1 and FIELD2 with blank suppression, you need

```
{ IF { MERGEFIELD FIELD1 } = 0 "" "TAG1: { MERGEFIELD FIELD1 }¶
" }{ IF { MERGEFIELD FIELD2 } = 0 "" "TAG2: { MERGEFIELD FIELD2 }¶
" }
```

e.g. in the case of `DOMESTIC` and `OTHER EARNINGS`, you need

```
{ IF { MERGEFIELD DOMESTIC_ALLOWANCE } = 0 "" "DOMESTIC: { MERGEFIELD DOMESTIC_ALLOWANCE }
" }{ IF { MERGEFIELD OTHER_ALLOWANCES } = 0 "" "OTHER EARNINGS: { MERGEFIELD OTHER_ALLOWANCES }
" }
```

Word's "blank line suppression" feature does not work in all circumstances, e.g. when you preview a merge, you may not see exactly the same results as when you merge. So you do need to test that this works for the type of merge you want to do.

That should work as long as the zeros are actually represented as 0, or 0.0, but if you *also* need to suppress the whole line when the value coming in is blank (i.e. "") it won't work. In that case, the following should work:

```
 { SET LFIELD { MERGEFIELD FIELDNAME } }{ IF { =LFIELD } = 0 "" "TAG: { MERGEFIELD FIELDNAME }¶
" }
```

(unfortunately you cannot just do

```
{ IF { =MERGEFIELD FIELDNAME } = 0 "" "TAG: { MERGEFIELD FIELDNAME }¶
" }
```

Because a lot of people around here like to experiment, one thing they may come across is that the following may work:

```
{ IF { =FIELDNAME } = 0 "" "TAG: { MERGEFIELD FIELDNAME }¶
" }
```

However, that relies on a very old and deprecated convention in Word, won't work for all types of data source, and should be avoided. It goes back to Word for Windows 1 where there was no { MERGEFIELD } field type.
)